# DQL findBy default query

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

What is DQL `findBy()` query syntax?

Like this:
    $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Users")->findBy($queryWhere);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create criteria for WHERE CLAUSE

```
$repository->findBy(['email' => 'test@test.com', 'city' => 'Berlin'])

SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = "test@test.com" AND city = "Berlin"
```

if you are interested, you can take a look in the method `getSelectSQL` under the following link

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Persisters.Entity.BasicEntityPersister.html#877-891

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is typically used with a property of the entity. It takes an array with the key as the property name on the entity and the value as what you're searching for.

Examples:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
    ->findBy(['id' => $id])
;

$this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
   ->findBy(['userName' => $userName])
;

$this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
   ->findBy(['email' => $email])
;
```

You can read more about it here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Comment: Tnx but i want to know what is dql syntax like `select u from ...`